# can I retrain google speech-to-text API

Tags: machine-learning, google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

The google speech-to-text is doing quite good but not for some specific domain like medicine's name, wine's name...
So is there a way that I can use google API and train 1 version of it for my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improving accuracy of Google Cloud Speech API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885317/improving-accuracy-of-google-cloud-speech-api)

Comment: no. I want to retrain it.